# Mysql query not working in PHP, works fine in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a function to find a timestamp in a table closest to the timestamp submitted. The query works fine in Mysql itsself (tested through phpmyadmin). However when i execute it through the php script the results are allways NULL.

All other query's in the script and other functions work correct. No errors are thrown either. I must be missing something but cannot see it. Any help here is appreciated.

Function:

```
function GetClosestMatch($timestamps){
    global $mysqli;
    $closestmatch = array();
    foreach($timestamps as $timestamp){
        if($stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM winlog_data ORDER BY ABS(timestamp - ? ) LIMIT 1")){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1,"i", $timestamp);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $db_timestamp);
            $closestmatch[] = $db_timestamp;
        }
    }
    return $closestmatch;
}
```

Timestamps array:

```
array (size=12)
0 => int 1451602800
1 => int 1454281200
2 => int 1456786800
3 => int 1459461600
4 => int 1462053600
5 => int 1464732000
6 => int 1467324000
7 => int 1470002400
8 => int 1472680800
9 => int 1475272800
10 => int 1477954800
11 => int 1480546800
```

Closestmatch array (result from function)

```
array (size=12)
0 => null
1 => null
2 => null
3 => null
4 => null
5 => null
6 => null
7 => null
8 => null
9 => null
10 => null
11 => null
```

Query result in PHPmyadmin:

```
SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM winlog_data ORDER BY ABS(timestamp - 1475272800 ) LIMIT 1 

timestamp  
1475271900
```

Comment: are you sure that variable $timestamp has the correct value when you use it in the mysql query? have you tried to echo inside the for each just to see what data it holds?

Comment: Hi Tony. I have indeed checked this. The timestamp is displayed correct in the functions for each loop.

Comment: what about fetch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing your call to  `mysqli_stmt_fetch`.

```
function GetClosestMatch($timestamps){
    global $mysqli;
    $closestmatch = array();
    foreach($timestamps as $timestamp){
        if($stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM winlog_data ORDER BY ABS(timestamp - ? ) LIMIT 1")){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1,"i", $timestamp);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $db_timestamp);
            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)) {
                $closestmatch[] = $db_timestamp;                     
            }

        }
    }
    return $closestmatch;
}
```

Also, you are mixing and matching procedural and oop mysqli_* calls. I'd advise you to pick one style and stick to it. (Not really related to your problem though)